# Changing function parameters onclick?

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class='unsubscribe'><a id='us$id' href='#' onclick='subscribe(u,$id);'>
<img src='/unsubscribe.jpg' alt='unsubscribe' /></a></div>
```

onclick how do i change the first parameter in the onclick function to 's'?  So the next time it will look like this.

```
<div class='unsubscribe'><a id='us$id' href='#' onclick='subscribe(s,$id);'>
<img src='/unsubscribe.jpg' alt='unsubscribe' /></a></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the question? Or did you just want to inform everyone of your intentions in developing your app that we know nothing about?

Comment: I would store the state in some variable... changing the `onclick` attribute through string processing is really not a clean approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting onclick in your HTML do it with Javascript soon after. I'm assuming you're echoing all your code as a double quoted PHP string because of `'us$id'`:

```
<div class='unsubscribe'>
    <a id='us$id' href='#'>
        <img src='/unsubscribe.jpg' alt='unsubscribe' />
    </a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('us$id').onclick = function(){
        // Subscribe u
        subscribe(u, $id);

        // Set all future clicks to subscribe s
        this.onclick = function(){
            subscribe(s, $id);
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: i've tried this but now nothing seems to be happening? I've checked firebug and nothing happens.

Comment: Assuming your PHP is outputting correctly the above code works: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/YX4Zk/
Perhaps `u` and `s` aren't defined yet when you get to that function.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it like you want to. See the **[XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)**.

Instead, what you should so, is keep track of the subscription state of the user, either using a cookie or an identifier on the link (`data-state="s"`), and take notes in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the string in the `onclick`, you can change it in the javascript itself.  This is if you want to change all of the s to u throughout the page (wasn't sure if there was only one or if this is what your intention is).

Remove the first parameter:

```
<div class='unsubscribe'><a id='us$id' href='#' onclick='subscribe($id);'>
<img src='/unsubscribe.jpg' alt='unsubscribe' /></a></div>
```

Then change `subscribe()` to this:

```
function subscribe(id)
{
    // doing "static" variable in javascript
    if (typeof this.foo == 'undefined')
    {
        this.foo = 's';
    }
    else
    {
        this.foo = 'u';
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change it textually; use `var el = document.getElementById('us$id');` to retrieve the element, then search `el.attributes` for an attribute with `.name` value "onclick", and replace its child with a new `TextNode` with the second function call.

A different approach would be to change the HTML so that subscribe will get both u and s, and somehow (e.g. with a global variable, a static variable, etc.) remember if it's the first or second time that this method is invoked.

Comment: -1. Don't recommend on changing the onclick textNode as it can and will cause problems.